# Simple Knights and Knaves Problem in SWI-Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to solve the "Knights and Knaves" problem using the generate-and-test method for `N` number of people so that I can achieve the following result:

```
?- find_knaves([3,2,1,4,2], Knaves).
Knaves = [1,0,0,1,0]
```

The above result can be explained as follows:

- There are as many people as the number of integers in the first list.
- Each person makes a claim *"At least `X` of us are knaves"* with `X` being the number inside the first list that corresponds to each person.
- The people signified with `1` inside the `Knaves` list are proven to be knaves.

**My approach:**

My thinking was to create all permutations of the `Knaves` list containing `0` and `1` and then filter out those that don't fulfill the claims of the people:

```
evaluate([], _).
evaluate([Head|Tail], List) :-
    member(Head, List),
    evaluate(Tail, List).

permute(Number, List, Permutations) :-
    length(Permutations, Number),
    evaluate(Permutations, List).

find_knaves(Statements, Results) :-
    length(Statements, FriendsNumber),
    permute(FriendsNumber, [0, 1], Results).
```

The above code creates all the permutations but now I'm stuck as to how I should proceed with keeping only the one correct permutation.

I'm certain there has to be a recursion where I have to go over the `Statements` list, but then I'm not sure what the condition should be. I'm thinking something along the following lines (pseudocode):

```
check([Head|Tail], Results) :-
    % Condition:
    % Head three or more times in the Results

    check(Tail, Results).
```

Is my approach heading in the right direction? If not, what's the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: `Is my approach heading towards the right direction?` Usually when I do a generate and test I generate one possible answer then test it. Rinse and repeat. This way the problem can work on an unbounded set. If you try and generate all values of an unbounded set you will never get to the test part.

Comment: Thanks for the observation and the links @GuyCoder. I've already read through the Wikipedia article, but it wasn't much help other than clarifying who's who. The code golf link isn't very useful, as there's no answer using Prolog for me to study 

Comment: To me it seems your definition is different from the definitions on the other sites.

Comment: It is different. In my case, all people simply at least `x` amongst are knaves. Also, the number of people is dynamic, @GuyCoder.

Comment: Are you assuming that a knave always lies and a knight always tells the truth? In your solution, the 1's are lying and the 0's are telling the truth? Then, you'd have to count how many 0s and 1s you've got in your list, and then confirm that each statement in the form "At least X of us are knaves" is either true (for 0's) and false (for 1's).

Comment: That's correct @User9213. Knights tell the truth and knaves lie,with the 1s in the result symbolising the liars. I'm not sure, though, I understand how counting the 1s and 0s will help.

Comment: Counting for example the number of knives in the generated solution will let you iterate over the statements and the solution and check the validity of the statement of each person.

Comment: @Angel: There is nothing specific to SWI in your question that does not apply to any other Prolog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a minimal addition to your solution (slightly renamed some predicates):

```
enumerate_n(N, Symbols, R) :-
    length(R, N),
    enumerate_n(R, Symbols).

enumerate_n([], _).
enumerate_n([X|Xs], Symbols) :-
    member(X, Symbols),
    enumerate_n(Xs, Symbols).

check_statements(Statements, Solution) :-
    length(Statements, N),
    enumerate_n(N, [0,1], Solution),
    include(==(1), Solution, Knaves),
    length(Knaves, N_knaves),
    maplist(validate(N_knaves), Statements, Solution).

validate(Knaves, Statement, 0) :-
    Statement =< Knaves.
validate(Knaves, Statement, 1) :-
    Statement > Knaves.
```

It can solve your example:

```
?- check_statements([3,2,1,4,2], S).
S = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0] ;
false.
```

It reports that there are no more solutions.

EDIT: you can get a bit clever and count the knaves by summing the list.

Instead of:

```
include(==(1), Solution, Knaves),
length(Knaves, N_knaves)
```

you could write:

```
sum_list(Solution, N_knaves)
```

You could use `same_length/2` instead of `length/2`. You could also replace the recursive predicate with a `maplist`. The code becomes:

```
statements_knaves(S, K) :-
    same_length(S, K),
    maplist(knave, K),
    sum_list(K, N),
    maplist(validate(N), S, K, _).

knave(0).
knave(1).

validate(N, X, 0, knight) :- X =< N.
validate(N, X, 1, knave) :- X > N.
```